# When should i use HTML5 or XFBML?

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

If the doctype is , should we be using the HTML5 facebook id, and when the doctype is using xhtml, should we be using XFBML?

Are these the determining factors?

When is using the IFRAME option more ideal than the HTML5 or XFBML?

There isnt much information on the facebook site

Thanks in advance